# Send N agents through directed graph with minimum cost

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

I have a problem of sending N agents from source vertex 'src' to a destination vertex 'dst' of a directed graph which **edges weights are increasing linear functions** of n (n is the number of agents that already passed through that edge).

[**Graph image:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJvWx.png)

**For example:**

```
scenario 1
Agent1 , src->A->dst , cost = 1+(-1) = 0 
Agent2 , src->A->dst , cost = 2+2 = 4
Agent3 , src->A->dst , cost = 3+5 = 8
overall cost = 0 + 4 + 8 =12

scenario 2
Agent1 , src->A->B->C->A->dst , cost = 1+0+0.5+(-2)+(-1) = -1.5
Agent2 , src->A->dst , cost = 2+2 = 4
Agent3 , src->A->dst , cost = 3+5 = 8
overall cost = -1.5 + 4 + 8 = 10.5
```

How to find paths of every agents that minimize overall cost?

Comment: Oh god, this is quite a difficult (and open) problem. Heuristics are your best bet

Comment: I think reinforcement learning might work. If there is no way to find an optimal solution, I'd still be interested in a good solution.